# Why is the trailing space removed from my attributes with shapefile?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a column called "nomen" for nomenclature, this text type field has spaces at the end of the text, example: "ho laa  ", but when saving the layer in shapefile format, the values ​​of the "nomen" field remain like this "ho laa", in short, without the final spaces.

Why does this happen?

I add the spaces manually and it doesn't work either, since if I reload the layer to QGIS the final spaces are removed again.

how I want it to be

[image]

[image]

how it looks when exporting:

[image]

Comment: @BERA the length of my field is 48 characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the dBase format the text fields are always filled with blanks till the full width of the field https://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm.

> Character - All OEM code page characters - padded with blanks to the
> width of the field.

It is not possible to distinct the blanks that belong to the data from those used for the fill. Use a better format like GeoPackage. Alternatively use some character(s) to end the attribute `"ho laa ,"`

Comment: OP could also use a UTF non-breaking space (U+00A0), but it could be truncated if in the 49th position.